# Supervised Learning and its number of predictable classes

Tags: machine-learning

I am just a beginner of the ML. I have gone through several websites for the basics and there are lots of unclear stuffs obviously to me and among below is the one.

In CNN(Convolutional Neural Network),  is it required to indicate to the system prior that how many number of classes available as a result?

I was going through below URL, and get this question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-Ol7ZB0MmU

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The final layer of the CNN depends on the quantity of output classes you have: one element for each class.  A CNN is built to handle a particular problem; this includes knowing the full shapes of the input and output.

For instance, the ILSVRC image data set comes with classified images, 1000 classes in all.  The topologies that learn on this data set have 1000 elements in the final layer.

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, my intake is that the CNN needs to be told earlier that what are the output classes it can expect right?

Comment: Right -- it has to know how many it needs to properly size the last layer.